# IdentityServer: Why is username and password wrong but can login through login page

Tags: authentication, access-token, identityserver4

I wanted to get the access token through the postman so I can use it on my mobile app to get token.

I can use the same password and username and login through the identity server login screen.

When I used the postman, it said invalid username/password? The configuration in the database is new for the identity server 4, am I missing some configuration in identity server.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I missing the service.AddAspIdentity() in the configueServices function